# How to increase setup time of a reg wired to an EBR FIFO? (Lattice FPGA)

Tags: fpga, timing, lattice

I'm using the built-in EBR FIFO of a Lattice FPGA:

```
reg fifoWrEn;
fifo fifo_inst(
    .WrClock (fifoWrClock),
    .WrEn (fifoWrEn),
    ...
);

always @(posedge fifoWrClock) begin
    fifoWrEn <= condition;
    ...
end
```

The datasheet shows that "Write enable" WrEn has an extended setup time t(SUWREN_EBR):

[image: setup]

which is around 0.2ns:

[image: setup]

I'm changing the value of fifoWrEn very frequently, potentially at each Write Clock cycle (50MHz = 20ns) and I see 'noise' and 'problem' because fifoWrEn doesn't seem to follow my logic once it reaches the EBR. In other words, data is stored when it should not and vice-versa. If I keep fifoWrEn high all the time, I don't see any issue.

I would like to add a constraint in the lpf file to extend the setup time of this specific reg.

Can I have such rule that and how to write it?

Comment: what is 'EBR FIFO"?

Comment: EBR means Embedded Block RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that I had trouble with the logic as well but it actually worked as intended. One just have to keep in mind that if WrEn is changed on the postive edge of WrClock it will be registered the next cycle. Alternatively one could opt for a "change on falling edge-read on rising edge" but this works poorly for machxos because they do not feature double edge internal logic IIRC.

Just check in my old source - it seems like using a simple intermediate input buffer should do the trick:

```
reg fifoWrEn;
reg [WIDTH-1:0] fifoInputBuffer;

fifo fifo_inst(
    .WrClock (fifoWrClock),
    .WrEn (fifoWrEn),
    .Data(fifoInputBuffer),
    ...
);

always @(posedge fifoWrClock) begin
    fifoWrEn <= condition;
    fifoInputBuffer <= data;
    ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It definitely helped me. My logic was completely wrong. After fixing it, I still think that data should be in the same cycle as WrEn and it's now working fine in my design. Perhaps my logic is doubly wrong wich would make it right... For sure, there is cycle delay between RdEn high and valid read data. This is clearly indicated in the datasheet. The datasheet doesn't say anything about WrEn.